# Warning "Views without any layout constraints may clip their content or overlap other views."

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, storyboard

Added UICliders and UILAbel and now see this warning "Views without any layout constraints may clip their content or overlap other views." in StoryBoard.

How to fix this warning?

Comment: adding contraints or uncheking the autolayout feature

Comment: Related: [Silence “Views without any layout constraints may clip their content” on a specific view controller that has preferredContentSize set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51463347/silence-views-without-any-layout-constraints-may-clip-their-content-on-a-speci)

Answer (score 2):

Adding subviews to an autolayout-enabled view  without applying layout constraints will produce unpredictable behaviors. You should either add constraints to those subviews or (not advisable) uncheck the autolayout flag